# Can anyone help identify this BMX??... please

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I got this bike but of a dumpster at a hotel, my guess is the owner had a room but never came back, so the hotel owners threw it out along with other stuff. It stuck out to me because of the x on the handle bars. It's been painted multiple times, so many layers. Any info would be GREATLY APPRECIATED....

Comment: This really needs more detail to have even a remote chance to be answered. Check https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: I was trying to add a photo but cant figure it out

Comment: Put the photo somewhere else and add a link here. Stackexchange probably doesn't allow photos from new users. And think why do you need to identify the brand in the first place. If it was valuable, it probably wouldn't have been left in dumpster and if you want to have it repaired, knowing the brand probably won't help.

Comment: Another possibility is that a hotel has open spaces on their grounds, and kids do like to yob-about in open spaces.  Could be the bike was left behind by accident, or simply dumped.  Perhaps it was stolen.     BMXs are notoriously hard to ID, and they're almost always some generic junk.  Knowing a brand name doesn't help with repairing the bike either, its not like a car.  I am curious to see these handlebars though.

Comment: @JessicaRene can you please try again to add photos ?